# Replace values in pandas dataframe utilizing a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have the following dataframe and dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 'a', 'B': 'a', 'C': 'a'}, {'A': 'b', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'b'}], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
df

     A    B    C
 0   a    a    a
 1   b    b    b

dic = { 'A': { 'a': 'label aa', 'b': 'label aaa'}, 'B': { 'a': 'label bb', 'b': 'label bbb'}, 'C': { 'a': 'label cc', 'b': 'label ccc'}}
dic

{'A': {'a': 'label aa', 'b': 'label aaa'},
 'B': {'a': 'label bb', 'b': 'label bbb'},
 'C': {'a': 'label cc', 'b': 'label ccc'}}
```

I want to match the df columns with the "outer keys". Once it finds a match, I would like to map the rows with the "inner key's values".

Here is my desired result:

```
     A           B          C
0  label aa   label bb   label cc
1  label aaa  label bbb  label ccc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `replace`, your dict is well created , the 1st key match the column, second match the value to replace , then the value is to_replace value

```
df.replace(dic)
Out[764]: 
           A          B          C
0   label aa   label bb   label cc
1  label aaa  label bbb  label ccc
```

Comment: I didn't know this.  +1

Comment: @spr_m if you like it , could you consider accept it ?

Comment: @Wen Done deal.